# Bootstrapping multiple variables in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, resampling

I would like to perform a bootstrap linear regression, because of concerns about normally distributed error terms. I have a data set that is big enough to ignore this fact, but I just want to double check if a linear regression model relying on analytically computed standard errors yields the same results as results obtained from a bootstrapped linear regression.

So far, I have used the follwing code:

```
Rel01 <- subset(
  Relevante_Variablen2,
  select = c(intr, sale_py_at_py, R_at_py,
             inflr, dt, re, txt)
)

x = as.data.frame(sapply(Rel01, as.numeric))
boxplot(x)

library(boot)

i<-nrow(x) #count number of rows for resampling 
g<-ncol(x) #count number of columns to step through with bootstrapping
boot.mean<-function(x,i){boot.mean<-mean(x[i])} #bootstrapping function to get the mean

boot_tabl <- apply(x,2,function(y){ 
  b<-boot(y,boot.mean,R=50000); 
  c(mean(b$t),boot.ci(b,type="perc", conf=0.95)$percent[4:5])
})

View(boot_tabl)
```

Everything seems to work (output is in the table shown below), but I do not know how to interpret the output from my approach.

| ^ | sale_py_at_py | intr | inflr | dt | re | txt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.0984438 | 0.01223 | 0.04243 | 200 | 400 | 1200 |
| 2 | 0.0974530 | 0.01191 | 0.04122 | 190 | 300 | 1000 |
| 3 | 0.0993230 | 0.01291 | 0.04256 | 210 | 405 | 1210 |

My data looks something like this:

| Name | Segment | Sale | Year | Asset | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3401 | 10000 | 2000 | 200000 | x |
| A | 3401 | 20000 | 2001 | 250000 | x |
| B | 2201 | 15000 | 2004 | 280000 | x |
| B | 2201 | 23000 | 2009 | 320000 | x |
| B | 2201 | 28000 | 2010 | 390000 | x |
| C | 2201 | 30000 | 2000 | 210000 | x |
| C | 2201 | 18000 | 2004 | 200000 | x |
| D | 1 | 28000 | 2000 | 400000 | x |
| D | 1 | 38000 | 2001 | 521000 | x |

Could anyone provide some directions on how I could bootstrap my linear regression analysis? And also tell me what the output of my regression is telling me exactly?

Edit:

```
original_data = Relevante_V03
original_model = lm01
set.seed(123) # fix random number generator for reproducibility

boot_lm <- function(original_data, original_model,
                    type = c('ordinary', 'param'),
                    B = 1000L, seed = 123) {
  set.seed(seed)
  betas_original_model <- coef(original_model)
  len_coef <- length(betas_original_model)
  mat <- matrix(rep(0L, B * len_coef), ncol = len_coef)
  if (type %in% 'ordinary') {
    n_rows <- length(residuals(original_model))
    for (i in seq_len(B)) {
      boot_dat <- original_data[sample(seq_len(n_rows), replace = TRUE), ]
      mat[i, ] <- coef(lm(terms(original_model), data = boot_dat))
    }
  }
  if (type %in% 'param') {
    X <- model.matrix(delete.response(terms(original_model)),
                      data = original_data)[, -1L]
    for (i in seq_len(B)) {
      mat[i, ] <- coef(lm(unlist(simulate(original_model)) ~ X,
                          data = original_data))
    }
  }
  confints <- matrix(rep(0L, 2L * len_coef), ncol = 2L)
  pvals <- numeric(len_coef)
  for (i in seq_len(len_coef)) {
    pvals[i] <- mean(abs(mat[, i] - mean(mat[, i])) > abs(betas_original_model[i]))
    confints[i, ] <- quantile(mat[, i], c(.025, 0.975))
  }
  names(pvals) <- names(betas_original_model)
  out <- data.frame(estimate = betas_original_model,
                    'lwr' = confints[, 1], 'upr' = confints[, 2],
                    p_value = pvals)
  return(out)
}


# linear model to be bootstrapped
my_split <- split(Relevante_V03, Relevante_V03$sic & Relevante_V03$fdyear) # split Relevante_03 by sic(Segment) & (fd)year 
out <- lapply(my_split, function(x) {
  lm(marketingspending ~ intr + sale_py_at_py + R_at_py, data = x) # perform linear regression on each company separately
})
ordinary <- lapply(out, function(x) coef(summary(x))) # obtain summary from linear models

# run bootstrap function on each of the levels of Name (company)
## this may take a while, as we have 50 Names (companies)...
for (i in seq_along(out)) {
  ordinary[[i]] <- boot_lm(original_data = my_split[[i]], original_model = out[[i]],
                           type = 'ordinary', B = 10000) # B is number of bootstrap samples
} 

# output
ordinary
```

The output looks like this:

$`TRUE`

| row. | estimate | lwr | upr | p_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 15647649 | 14131807 | 17268286 | 0 |
| intr | -64880946 | -92974339 | -36369417 | 0 |
| sale_py_at_py | -4520320 | -5741252 | -3359742 | 0 |
| R_at_py | -1904298824 | -23372044347 | -1564292455 | 0 |

My questions to this are:

-Does everything looks to you fine?

-Why are all the p-Values 0 and how can I get to see a more detailed value of p? Because they should not be 0

Thanks to the comment (@Dion Groothof) I tried the approach. Could someone tell me if I am doing everything right in this approach?

Comment: You may want to consult [my recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70802316/10852113) on how to obtain valid inference from linear regression models using a parametric or non-parametric bootstrap procedure.

Comment: Thank you @DionGroothof I looked into it and I think I made everything correct could you double check if it is fine please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by the OP, this should be the appropriate way to proceed with in *his* specific case.

It is not necessary (and I would even advise against it) to change the arguments within the function itself. Instead, specify appropriate character stings and integers as arguments in a call to the function. This should be done as follows.

First we specify our linear model.

```
# linear model
fm0 <- lm(marketingspending ~ intr + inflr + sale_py_at_py+ R_at_py +
            + dt + re + txt , data = Relevante_V03)
```

Then, we run the function as is. For more information on the function's arguments, refer to [my recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70802316/10852113).

```
boot_lm <- function(original_data, original_model,
                    type = c('ordinary', 'param'),
                    B = 1000L, seed = 1) {
  set.seed(seed)
  betas_original_model <- coef(original_model)
  len_coef <- length(betas_original_model)
  mat <- matrix(rep(0L, B * len_coef), ncol = len_coef)
  if (type %in% 'ordinary') {
    n_rows <- length(residuals(original_model))
    for (i in seq_len(B)) {
      boot_dat <- original_data[sample(seq_len(n_rows), replace = TRUE), ]
      mat[i, ] <- coef(lm(terms(original_model), data = boot_dat))
    }
  }
  if (type %in% 'param') {
    X <- model.matrix(delete.response(terms(original_model)),
                      data = original_data)[, -1L]
    for (i in seq_len(B)) {
      mat[i, ] <- coef(lm(unlist(simulate(original_model)) ~ X,
                          data = original_data))
    }
  }
  confints <- matrix(rep(0L, 2L * len_coef), ncol = 2L)
  pvals <- numeric(len_coef)
  for (i in seq_len(len_coef)) {
    pvals[i] <- mean(abs(mat[, i] - mean(mat[, i])) > abs(betas_original_model[i]))
    confints[i, ] <- quantile(mat[, i], c(.025, 0.975))
  }
  names(pvals) <- names(betas_original_model)
  out <- data.frame(estimate = betas_original_model,
                    'lwr' = confints[, 1], 'upr' = confints[, 2],
                    p_value = pvals)
  return(out)
}
```

Finally, we specify character strings and integers as arguments in a call to `boot_lm()` to have it tailor-made for *your* specific case.

```
# non-parametric bootstrap
boot_lm(original_data = Relevante_V03, original_model = fm0,
        type = 'ordinary', B = 1e4, seed = 59385)

# parametric bootstrap
boot_lm(original_data = Relevante_V03, original_model = fm0,
        type = 'param', B = 1e4, seed = 59385)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly fine but if I use a modified regression (as I have to do) it does not work.            Relevante_V032 <- Relevante_V03 %>% 
  mutate(fdyear = factor(fdyear),
         sic = factor(sic)) %>% 
  group_by(fdyear, sic) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 10) %>% 
  group_split()                                                                                            Is there an easy solution to that problem?

Comment: Could you please put into words what exactly you would like to do? I never use `tidyverse` approaches that is.

Comment: Okay: I have a data set that I need to group and or divide. I need to get groups of companies that have the same segment (sic) and that have the same date. (my data provides information per line for one company for one year; also visible in the table of original question). After I got groups of companies (same year and same sic) I need to filter out the groups that have below 10 entries.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, it seems like you have repeated measurements of `Sale` and `Asset`. Why not use a mixed model to obtain inference? This approach would have three advantages: 1) it is more efficient; 2) it provides valid inference when you have missing observations of the so-called MCAR and MAR type (because it internally imputes missing values, if you will); 3) it approriately accounts for the correlation between the repeated measures (provided that the random-effects structure is correctly specified).

Comment: Those two variables (sale_py_at_py, R_at_py) I need to take in context of the regression. The missing observation are good to filter my data because I got so much data (over 250.000 lines) that my laptop is not capable of doing the regression hahaha (have to load over night). In the end I have over 190 groups and with 10 or more entries that's still a data set big enough to be relevant. Therefore I like my approach. So do you know a way to do the regression with your approach and my beginning?

Comment: Versteht jemand, was der p-Wert hier angibt? Und wie man sich beim p-Wert mehr ausgeben lassen kann als nur 4 Nachkommerstellen?